# Crop the tensor using mask

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a question on cropping/reshaping. Let’s say if we already know a range, for example, (500,500) and I have an image of (496,504), if I want to use a mask to padding missing pixels and crop additional pixels so that reshape the image to (500,500). Is there anyway to do this by mask?

Is there an elegant way to apply this range tensor on the image tensor and crop accordingly ? (such as mask?)
I have also tried using reduce function to build a mask to filter out the out-of-range pixels.

```
mask = reduce(torch.logical_and, (img_tensor[:,:, ?,:] >= range[1],
                                         img_tensor[:,:, ?,:] < range[3],
                                         img_tensor[:,:, :,?]  >= range[0],
                                         img_tensor[:,:, :,?] < range[2]))
```

The issue is I don’t know what to put at the position of “?” so that it compares the value at that dimension to the range value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make a tensor of your desired final shape with a dummy value (e.g. 0). Find the minimum dimension between this and the original tensor, and use these values to select which values of the new tensor to replace:

```
masked = torch.zeros([3,500,500])
d1 = min(img_tensor.shape[1],masked.shape[1])
d2 = min(img_tensor.shape[2],masked.shape[2])
masked[:,:d1,:d2] = img_tensor[:,:d1,:d2]
```